# Check if the inputted string contains something on my list

Tags: java, string

Let's say i input "i love you". If you have typed a statement that **contains** a "love" word then it will do something.

Comment: does your list contain the word "love" or a phrase/sentence containing the word "love" ?

Comment: If what is syntax to do that because i only knew if the inputted string is equal to a particular word then it will do something. NOT contains a word.

Comment: You might wish to express yourself more clearly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
List<String> keywords = // your words
for (String key : keywords) {
    if (yourPhrase.contains(key)) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

It should do the job.